# PWA Manifest can't find resources

Tags: progressive-web-apps, manifest, vite

I'm trying to make a PWA using Vite and the Quasar framework (Vite Plugin).
My manifest and icons are all stored in the root folder of my project, but the manifest somehow can't find them.

When I run my application in dev mode, everything works fine, but when I build and host my application the manifest file gets a lot of errors:

- property 'start_url' ignored, URL is invalid
- property 'src' ignored,
  URL is invalid
- Icon URL 'android-chrome-256x256.png' failed to parse
- ...

This is my *site.webmanifest* file:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "short_name": "foo",
  "start_url": "/index.html",
  "id": "/",
  "description": "foo",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "background_color": "#D3D5E1",
  "theme_color": "#D3D5E1",
  "orientation": "portrait-primary",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/android-chrome-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/android-chrome-256x256.png",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "/android-chrome-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable"
    }
  ]
}
```

I link to it in my index.html file: `<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest" />`

Could somebody please tell me what I'm missing?
It seems to me I'm doing something wrong in my relative paths, but I tried a lot to no avail.
I've also tried to place the icons in the public folder, but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also ran into this issue in the past. My problem was that the PWA was not uploaded to the root of my remote storage. It was uploaded to www.example.com/PWA

I got rid of the error by adding '/PWA/' to the beginning of all paths.

So in your case, if your PWA is accessed via www.example.com/myPWA. Then try renaming your paths to something like 

"start_url": "myPWA/index.html"     ....also, sometimes, all you need to do is remove the opening /